# Does the spring jms message jistener of spring gets initialised when the contianer is still in the process of getting up and running

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, websphere-8, spring-jms

Does spring jms message listener gets initialised and picks the message from queue while my ear is getting up and the we application is still in the process of getting up on websphere. As we are using spring beans, so can it be possible that ear is still getting up but jms-message listener has picked up the message from queue.
Or Till the ear will not get up and running until then the message would not be picked up from queue.

Thanks 
Ram

Answer (score 2):

I have used **Spring batch** and **Spring integratio**n in a single project .
We have used tomcat for deployment and gradle as a build tool .

JmsListeners will get initialized only when the war is fully deployed , up and running , till then no JMS messages will be picked up by the JMSListener .

You don't have to worry about loosing messages when the listeners is still in the process of initialisation .